# Node Puppeteer Promise.all issues when viewing different pages at one time

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, puppeteer

I'm fairly new to web scraping and have been using the Puppeteer library to do so. I'm managing to get most things working but when trying to promise.all and have a second function being triggered to go away to two separate pages it's always the last page in the promise.all map that it goes to, even though in the debugger it should have gone to the page in question.

The function that triggers the fetch of the data looks like the code example below:

```js
const fetchSeasonUrls = async () => {
  const driver = await configuration.getDriver(baseUrl);

  const watchList = await fetchWatchList(driver);

  // When the function below is hit the end result looks like example result one below
  const watchListSeasons = await Promise.all(
    watchList.map(async show => {
      await tvSplurgeio.getSeasonData(driver, show);
    })
  );

  // When the function below is hit the end result looks like example result two below
  const showOne = await tvSplurgeio.getSeasonData(driver, watchList[0]);
  const showTwo = await tvSplurgeio.getSeasonData(driver, watchList[1]);
}
```

Example-Result-One

```
[
  [S01, S02, ..., S31],
  [S01, S02, ..., S31]
]
```

Example-Result-Two

```
const showOne = [S01, S02, ..., S10];
const showTwo = [S01, S02, ..., S31];
```

The second result is correct as it's navigating to the correct show page and pulling the season data back with it but when it's in a promise it seems to return the last thing in the array x number of times.

The puppeteer code that is returning this data looks like so:

```js
const tvSplurgeio = {
  getSeasonData: async (driver, show) => {
    let navigationPromise = driver.page.waitForNavigation();
    await driver.page.goto(show.url);
    await navigationPromise;

    await driver.page.waitForSelector(".sidebar-seasons");
    const seasonData = await driver.page.evaluate(() => {
      const allSeasons = document.querySelectorAll(
        'li[class*="sidebar-season"]'
      );

      let data = [];
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(allSeasons, season => {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(season.children, child => {
          const seasonNumber = parseInt(child.innerText.split(" ")[1], 10);
          data.push(
            seasonNumber < 10 ? `S0${seasonNumber}` : `S${seasonNumber}`
          );
        });
      });
      return data;
    });

    await navigationPromise;
    return seasonData;
  },
}
```

I have tried a whole bunch of things from the page.waitFor() to awaiting navigation promises and I'm not quite sure if it's just a misunderstanding of what can be done with this library in promise.alls.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that your issue is coming from using `Promise.all`. Also, `map` is more suitably used when you want to perform an operation on elements of an array, and then return a new array with the modifications.

Since it seems that you are not using the returned value from `map`, I suggest instead trying `forEach` and simply pushing each value returned from `tvSplurgeio.getSeasonData()` to a new array `seasonData`.

```
const watchList = await fetchWatchList(driver);
const seasonData = [];

watchList.forEach(async show => {
  seasonData.push(await tvSplurgeio.getSeasonData(driver, show));
});
```